# How to fix this error when installing APEX 22.2?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have tried to install APEX 22.2 on Windows 11 for a project, the problem is that I got the following errors. I already checked if I had a previously installed version of APEX, I even used the famous @apxremov.sql to fix it. But I suspect that even the uninstall doesn't work properly.

What I am doing wrong? These are the errors below, and what I do for the install:

`SQL> @apexins APEX APEX TEMP /i/`

I got the following errors:

```
Performing installation in multitenant container database in the background.
The installation progress is spooled into apexins_cdb*.log files.

Please wait...

catcon::set_log_file_base_path: ALL catcon-related output will be written to [C:\apex\apexins_cdb_catcon_14048.lst]

catcon::set_log_file_base_path: catcon: See [C:\apex\apexins_cdb*.log] files for output generated by scripts

catcon::set_log_file_base_path: catcon: See [C:\apex\apexins_cdb_*.lst] files for spool files, if any

catcon::validate_con_names: PDB$SEED is not open

catcon::get_affected_containers: Unexpected error returned by validate_con_names for default Container list

catcon::catconInit2: Unexpected error returned by get_affected_containers

Unexpected error encountered in catconInit2; exiting


Installation completed. Log files for each container can be found in:

apexins_cdb*.log

You can quickly scan for ORA errors or compilation errors by using a utility
like grep:

grep ORA- *.log
grep PLS- *.log
```

Comment: Which pluggable database are you installing APEX into? What errors are in the log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you installing the Full development environment?
If yes, the command should read:

```
@apexins.sql SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/
```

See [Database > Oracle > APEX > Release - 22.1 Installation Guide - 5.3.3 Installing Oracle APEX into a CDB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/htmig/installing-apex-into-different-PDBs.html#GUID-711396F6-DC1C-4EF8-8CA5-4C36E8615DFD)

Comment: You said that "the command should read `@apexins.sql SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/`. Why do you think so? What's wrong with command Simon ran?